# Refactoring a MySQL query with a number of inner selects to joins

Tags: mysql

I made a query that relied on a bunch of inner selects [since when I was logically working out the relationships of the query in our humongous database, it made "logical" sense].

However, right now I want to refactor my query to use `JOIN`s instead, since I read on a blog that nested selects isn't good for readability.

```
/**
 * Returns the city area ID based on the dish
 * @param $dish_id ID of the dish
 * @return mixed City area ID
 */
public function getCityAreaByDishId(
    $dish_id
) {
    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT
        m.city_area_id as city_area_id
        FROM menus m
        WHERE m.id = (
            SELECT c.menu_id
            FROM oc_category c
            WHERE category_id = (
                SELECT oc.category_id
                FROM oc_category c
                LEFT JOIN oc_category oc
                ON (c.parent_id = oc.category_id)
                WHERE c.category_id = (
                    SELECT ptc.category_id
                    FROM oc_product_to_category ptc
                    WHERE ptc.product_id = $dish_id
                )
            )
        );
    ");
    return $query->row['city_area_id'];
}
```

I am a beginner at MySQL, and I want to form some good habits in the beginning. Could someone help me or give me some tips on how to refactor this for better readability?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you must use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` on this row `LEFT JOIN oc_category oc` ?

Comment: I meant to say `JOIN`, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step, look at this

```
SELECT oc.category_id
FROM oc_category c
JOIN oc_category oc
ON (c.parent_id = oc.category_id)
WHERE c.category_id = (
    SELECT ptc.category_id
    FROM oc_product_to_category ptc
    WHERE ptc.product_id = $dish_id
)
```

it can be changed to

```
SELECT oc.category_id
FROM oc_category c
JOIN oc_category oc ON (c.parent_id = oc.category_id)
JOIN oc_product_to_category ptc ON ptc.category_id = c.category_id AND ptc.product_id = $dish_id
```

so the whole query will be

```
    SELECT m.city_area_id as city_area_id
    FROM menus m
    WHERE m.id = (
        SELECT c.menu_id
        FROM oc_category c
        WHERE category_id = (
            SELECT oc.category_id
            FROM oc_category c
            JOIN oc_category oc ON (c.parent_id = oc.category_id)
            JOIN oc_product_to_category ptc ON ptc.category_id = c.category_id AND ptc.product_id = $dish_id
        )
    )
```

The next step, let's change next level

```
        SELECT c.menu_id
        FROM oc_category c
        WHERE category_id = (
            SELECT oc.category_id
            FROM oc_category c
            JOIN oc_category oc ON (c.parent_id = oc.category_id)
            JOIN oc_product_to_category ptc ON ptc.category_id = c.category_id AND ptc.product_id = $dish_id
```

to

```
        SELECT c.menu_id
        FROM oc_category c
        JOIN oc_category oc ON (c.parent_id = oc.category_id)
        JOIN oc_product_to_category ptc ON ptc.category_id = c.category_id AND ptc.product_id = $dish_id
```

so the query becomes

```
SELECT m.city_area_id AS city_area_id
FROM menus m
WHERE m.id = (
    SELECT c.menu_id
    FROM oc_category c
    JOIN oc_category oc ON (c.parent_id = oc.category_id)
    JOIN oc_product_to_category ptc ON ptc.category_id = c.category_id AND ptc.product_id = $dish_id
)
```

The last step and the final query

```
SELECT m.city_area_id AS city_area_id
FROM menus m
JOIN oc_category c ON (m.id = c.menu_id)
JOIN oc_category oc ON (oc.parent_id = c.category_id)
JOIN oc_product_to_category ptc ON ptc.category_id = oc.category_id AND ptc.product_id = $dish_id
```

Anyone, correct me if I'm wrong.

EDIT: Changed the query to the right one by changing the table prefixes.

Comment: Hmm, it seems in your `last step and final query`, your result when used in MySQL would return undefined index, meaning, the result was an empty set. I'm not quite sure what's wrong with it at the moment, but I'm investigating. I am breaking the query down, and the empty set begins to return on `join oc_category oc on (c.parent_id = oc.category_id);`

Comment: Maybe the reason is that we've removed the `LEFT JOIN` and have made it to be `JOIN`. Have you tried to change the `$dish_id` variable's value?

Comment: I got it. I'm editing your change right now, but my internet is being goofy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I particularly enjoyed the way you broke everything down.